# Let x and y be integers, prove that if 3 doesn't divide x and 3 doesn't divide y then 3 divides $x^2 - y^2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let x and y be integers, prove that if $3 \nmid x$ and $3 \nmid y$ then 
$3 \mid (x^2 - y^2)$

Attemmpt:

The only thing i get out of this is that there is a difference of squares: $$(x^2 - y^2) = (x-y)(x+y) $$

Other than that i am  stuck. Perhaps a hint before a full blown solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**
If $3\not\mid x,$ then $x^2\equiv1\pmod3.$
Apply this to $x$ and $y,$ and conclude.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh i see exactly what to do now using the properties of modular arithmatic, but why is $ x^2 \equiv1 \pmod3$ ?

Comment: If $3 \not\mid x$, then either $x \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$ or $x \equiv 2\pmod{3}$. Then, we have either $x^2 \equiv 1^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$ or $x^2 \equiv 2^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$.

Comment: Whether $x \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ or $x \equiv 2 \pmod 3$, $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$.

Comment: More symetrically, if $x$ is not a multiple of $3$, then $x\equiv \pm 1\pmod{3}$.

Comment: Urgh. That's right . For a given modulus m, each integer is congruent to exactly one of {0,1,... m-1}.

Comment: Or you can resort to Fermat's little theorem: If $p$ is a prime number, then $\forall x \not\equiv0\pmod p, x^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod p.$ Taking $p=3$ here gives another way of proving the proposition: divide the equation by $y,$ which is possible as $3$ does not divide $y,$ and then the equation becomes $(xy^{-1})^2\equiv1\pmod3,$ exactly Fermat's little theorem.

Answer (score 3):

Factoring, is not the best way.  But for fun let us use factoring.

If neither $x$ nor $y$ is divisible by $3$, then $x\equiv y\pmod{3}$ or $x\equiv -y\pmod{3}$. In the first case, $3$ divides $x-y$. In the second, $3$ divides $x+y$. So in either case $3$ divides $(x-y)(x+y)$.

Answer (score 0):

If $3 \nmid x$, then $x = 3k + 1$ or $3k + 2$. In the former case, $x^2 = (3k + 1)^2 = 9k^2 + 6k + 1$ which can be restated as $3j + 1$, while in the latter case, $x^2 = (3k + 2)^2 = 9k^2 + 12k + 4$, which can also be restated as $3j + 1$. In the notation of congruences, if $3 \nmid x$, then $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$.

Let's say $x^2 = 3j + 1$ and $y^2 = 3h + 1$. Then $$x^2 - y^2 = (3j + 1) - (3h + 1) = 3j - 3h = 3(j - h).$$ With congruences, you can just do $x^2 - y^2 \equiv 1 - 1 = 0 \pmod 3$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $3$ does not divide $x$ and $y$ means that $3$ does not divide $x^2$ and $y^2$.

Hence, $x^2$ and $y^2$ leave remainder 1 when divided by $3$. This is a simple rule of perfect square numbers.

Let $x^2=3q+1$ and $y^2=3p+1$.

> $\therefore x^2-y^2=3q+1-3p+1=3(q-p)\implies 3$ is a factor of $x^2-y^2$.
>
> Thus, the answer follows.